# Entering Right Ascension in AstroPosition

Tags: astronomy

In the new Mathematica 13.2 the AstroGraphics let you plot the sky, e.g. centered at a specific coordinate. However, I cannot figure out how to enter efficiently the value for {right ascension, declination}. Below is my best outcome so far for an object at 5h 13m 13s, 2d 51m 18s, i.e. FromDMS works fine for declination, but not that great for right ascension.

```
zygo = 
 AstroPosition[{FromDMS[{360\*5/24, 13\*15, 13\*15}], 
   FromDMS[{2, 51, 18}]}, "Equatorial"]
```

Any ideas? (Or maybe I am just overlooking something obvious...)

Comment: [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7of9a.png) from the cloud.

Comment: `AstroPosition[FromDMS /@ {15 {5, 13, 13}, {2, 51, 18}}, "Equatorial"]`